# Document classification problem

Tags: self-study, classification, maximum-likelihood, naive-bayes

> Assume we have $L$ labelled documents, and $U$ unlabeled ones, where all the documents from class $k$ were generated from a multinomial or Naive Bayes distribution with parameter $\theta_k$, and there are a total of $K$ classes. Let each point $x_n$ be a $D$ dimensional vector.
>
> a) What is the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta_k$ using only the labeled data?
>
> b) What is the mean squared error of this estimator?
>
> c) We can construct an estimator for $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_K$ that uses the unlabeled as well as labeled data by maximizing the likelihood of the observed data. Write down the log-likelihood function in this case.
>
> d) Under what conditions would the MLE in case (a) converge to the true parameter? Can these conditions be relaxed if we also use unlabeled data as in (c)?

I am not sure as to how to solve each of these. For part (a), is this the likelihood
$$
l(\theta_{k,d}) = \prod_{n=1}^N p(y_n)^{I(y_n = k)} \left[ \prod_{d=1}^D p(x_n^d | y_n = k) \right]^{I(y_n = k)}
$$
that I should maximize with respect to $\theta_{k,d}$? If so, is the estimator
$$
\theta_{k,d} = \frac{N_k}{N}
$$
where $N_k$ is the number of data points labeled $y_n = k$?

Can anyone verify this? And can you give me suggestions as to how to solve the remaining parts? Thanks